# Why my Questions closed is not opened after 2 times re-editing..why not admins re-edit themself?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request

I have edited  two time and  remove all questing leaving one and question still explained to make them understand what i am talking about still question is  not opened and even banned to ask more questions kindly open my question ..where and how can i remind and appeal for opening the question or allowing me to ask new question if possible.

Comment: What questions are you referring to exactly? Your urgency is not a factor in the consideration if your contribution should remain open or closed. Once closed, a question can take several days, once it receives an edit specifying it should be eligible to be reopened. Which is the reason it’s important to ask the question, properly and detailed, when you first submit it.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1788503/how-to-backup-overwrite-recovery-parition-with-own-custom-replaced-backup-file

Comment: This question doesn't include enough details. Remember that each question, even on Meta, should be self-contained. While there might be very generous community members that might look at your activity to figure out what you are talking about, that is not something that you should expect as something normal. On the other hand, it might be worth mentioning that some community members are participating in the moderation-strike. These days, it might take longer than usual for the people still looking at the review queues to go through all the reopening requests.

Answer (score 5):

Your initial 'question' were actually three, all separately requiring pretty complex answers. PC magazines can fill an article with each of the three questions alone. It then became 4 questions and then was closed.

In comments people tried to explain to you why. It then became two questions and finally 1. Currently there's 3 votes in favor of re-opening. It's still a clumsy question IMO.

Aside from number of questions there may be other issues with the question.

I interpret question as: "How can I replace the manufacturers image in the factory recovery partition with my own?".

Potential issue 1: I can not imagine you're the first person asking this on SuperUser so there may be duplicates. If Duplicates exist this again is reason for closure.

Potential issue 2: You yourself point to various internet resources so then the question arises, did you try these and if you ran into an issue, what was it and what did you try to resolve it? You should describe these issues and solution to prevent from getting the exact same answers as described in the resources you linked to.

I am relatively new to SuperUser (had an account longer but became more active no too long ago) but the way I understand this is, you want your question answered, but SuperUser wants and a good question and the best possible answer so it becomes a reference for people who have the same question some time in the future.

Comment: Bro Thanks alot  for replying and make me understand my mistake and guding me. yes its true there many articles on internet available. I can try them but to try each one methods and discussing the problems in each methods is time consuming and risky. Its better to ask super experts experienced users which method is good and risk free and take a chance on it. So i take opinion of experts super users.

Comment: bro i used to write small questions then members o experts used to say elborate and expand we cant uderstand now i elborate others say its clumsy too long. i cant  satisfy  all  members experts reading patterns and taste. its better if they edit themself as per there thoughts views and taste.

Comment: @Androidquery You found 10 different guides, so you've asked experts to write an 11th one especially for you? It looks like 10 experts already put some effort into addressing your problem, now it's your turn.

Comment: @Androidquery - “I can try them but to try each one methods and discussing the problems in each methods is time consuming and risky.” - The fact they are time consuming isn’t a reason not to try them, and expecting this community to determine which of those methods you would find acceptable, is unreasonable since you haven’t even tried any of them. The fact they might be risky, unspecified mind you, is a different story altogether

Answer (score 4):

You mention writing "small questions" and being told they need more details, and then you've had multiple questions closed for asking too many questions, or being too "big", I suppose, to use a consistent phrasing.

The right question "size" will have:

1. one specific question
2. all of the information necessary for us to understand that specific question
3. all of the efforts you've already made to try to solve it

**First**, the question itself needs to be clear. It could be helpful to have the specific question at the beginning and the end. That is just good, clear writing. It isn't necessary, but it can be a good habit for making sure it is clear what you are asking.

**Second**, your question needs to have all of the information necessary for someone else to understand what you are asking. This means telling us precisely what happened prior to the error, the error messages, the details of the system you're working on (model, brand, version, publisher, year, patch version, etc). We only know what you tell us. Think of it like this: You're our eyes, ears, and hands, and you're coming to this site for some brains to make sense of everything your eyes and ears and hands are telling you, but the brain doesn't know anything except what the eyes, ears, and hands can tell it.

**Third**, you need to "show your homework". This is a free site "staffed" ("communitied"?) by regular people who have experience and knowledge who do not belong to the site and are not paid by the site or anything else. We come here because we want to. We answer questions because we want to. This not me saying "RESPECT MAH AUTHORITAH!" It IS me saying "a question that shows some effort on the part of the one asking will be better received". Also, showing your research and what you've tried means we know what NOT to suggest, so we won't be wasting our time telling you what you've already learned and tried.

On a point related to #3, telling us you found a solution but you don't like it, like you do when you say

> There are some findings while google but they told procedure how to do through windows commonds.

That tells people who may have answers that you're not really willing to work hard for a solution, even if you don't intend to say that. You DID find a solution, but you don't want to try it. Windows commands are likely the only way to do what you want to do in that question. Commands (or, what you may actually mean, a "command line interface") have been around a long time, and are still the only way to do many of the deep down changes even in very graphical OSes like Windows.

**To summarize**, your questions need to be clear and specific, they need to have all of the information you can give that focuses on one specific question, and they need to clearly demonstrate what you have already learned and tried.